# Can I be confident that I will not lose data in Reference managers?

Tags: reference-managers

What if the company behind a reference manager or the people behind it decided to stop the application development and just delete it from the internet. In this case I may lose all my data. So, what is the options that prevent this from happening?

Comment: I've never lost any BibTeX data.

Comment: You should never be confident about losing any kind of data under any circumstances, even with multiple off-site backups. Just the way you need to think and act about it.

Comment: Never rely on closed source products.

Answer (score 4):

You could make sure to use one that allows exporting the data into an open format (which I think most do?) and use that functionality to make backups every now and then (ideally regularly). You probably want to backup that data anyway! (By the way, that piece of advice is applicable to much more than just reference managers.) If you want more control, you could also use an open-source reference manager and decide where the data is stored. Personally I use JabRef, but there are a [number to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software) depending on your needs and preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Actually any electronic resource is at risk. The solution is regular backups that you control yourself.

You don't lose money (generally) from banks because banks are regulated, forcing them to keep redundancy in their records and regularizing their client relationships. None of that is true with any unregulated cloud-like resource. The news has stories fairly regularly of lost data through both error and hacking.

To protect yourself, you can make copies of things you enter when you enter them, and manage your own backups of those copies. Use formats least likely to be abandoned over time - plain text, for example. Use media for backups that will last and continue to be readable. When standards change, update to new media. (I have about a thousand unreadable 3 inch floppy disks, sadly.)

Use the manager as a convenience but not as a bank vault.

You can hope for the best, but prepare for the worst.